# Associate MasterData with ReportSummary to print together

Tags: delphi, fastreport

I created a bill with fastreport.

I use:

```
ReportTitle,
PageHeader,
MasterData,
ReportSummary,
PageFooter.
```

it works very well, except when I have 20 to 25 items. the ReportSummary and PageHeader are print on the next page without MasterData.

Can we associate MasterData with ReportSummary to print together ?.

The size of MasterData is variable.

Comment: I'm not used to fast report, but can't adjust the controls programmatically?

Comment: which generator do you use ?.

Comment: In our Apps we use a Custom made generator that allows us to do what ever we want with the data programmatically (we do not believe in RAD when it comes to reporting because of localization issues and others). the thing is basically a set of classes that can be used on TCanvas Family to generate our reports.

Comment: now I understand your answer.
the goal is not just to make an impression but to give the user the possibility to customize it to the maximum.
the print generators are puzzles the first time but after it's a breeze. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I completely deleted '***ReportSummary***' and I put are contained in '***PageFooter***' with ***visible property*** of the content to '***False***' and I make it to '***True***' in the last page and it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

Select the ReportSummary field and look if the property 'StartNewPage' is checked.
I've encoutered this problem myself, and this was the solution.

Comment: Thank you, but do not correct my problem.
but I completely deleted '**ReportSummary**' and I put are contained in '**PageFooter**' with the **visible property** of the content to '**False**' and I make it to '**True**' in the last page and it works fine.